# error installing scikit-garden on windows 10

Tags: scikit-learn

I get an error code when I try to install scikit-garden and not sure how to fix it.  The full error code is too long to post but the same issue appears to be presented at the following link:
https://github.com/scikit-garden/scikit-garden/issues/46

however the solution suggested does not work.  Thanks!

```
(C:\Anaconda3) C:\Users\Kyle M\Documents>pip install scikit-garden
Collecting scikit-garden
  Using cached scikit-garden-0.1.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-garden)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-garden)
Requirement already satisfied: scikit-learn>=0.18 in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-garden)
Requirement already satisfied: cython in c:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit-garden)
Building wheels for collected packages: scikit-garden
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for scikit-garden ... error
  Complete output from command C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\KYLEM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-6w93qccz\\scikit-garden\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\KYLEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp2yepl3frpip-wheel- --python-tag cp36:
  Appending skgarden.mondrian.tree configuration to skgarden.mondrian
  Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'skgarden.mondrian' to 'skgarden.mondrian.tree')
  Appending skgarden.mondrian.ensemble configuration to skgarden.mondrian
  Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'skgarden.mondrian' to 'skgarden.mondrian.ensemble')
  Appending skgarden.mondrian configuration to skgarden
  Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'skgarden' to 'skgarden.mondrian')
  Appending skgarden.quantile configuration to skgarden
  Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'skgarden' to 'skgarden.quantile')
  Appending skgarden configuration to
  Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from '' to 'skgarden')
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running config_cc
  unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
  running config_fc
  unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
  running build_src
  build_src
  building extension "skgarden.mondrian.tree._tree" sources
  building extension "skgarden.mondrian.tree._splitter" sources
  building extension "skgarden.mondrian.tree._criterion" sources
  building extension "skgarden.mondrian.tree._utils" sources
  build_src: building npy-pkg config files
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden
  copying skgarden\forest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden
  copying skgarden\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden
  copying skgarden\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian
  copying skgarden\mondrian\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian
  copying skgarden\mondrian\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
  copying skgarden\quantile\ensemble.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
  copying skgarden\quantile\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
  copying skgarden\quantile\tree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
  copying skgarden\quantile\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
  copying skgarden\quantile\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\ensemble
  copying skgarden\mondrian\ensemble\forest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\ensemble
  copying skgarden\mondrian\ensemble\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\ensemble
  copying skgarden\mondrian\ensemble\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\ensemble
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\tree
  copying skgarden\mondrian\tree\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\tree
  copying skgarden\mondrian\tree\tree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\tree
  copying skgarden\mondrian\tree\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\tree
  running build_ext
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  customize MSVCCompiler
  customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
  building 'skgarden.mondrian.tree._tree' extension
  compiling C sources
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden\mondrian
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden\mondrian\tree
  cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcskgarden\mondrian\tree\_tree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden\mondrian\tree\_tree.obj -O3

  error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcskgarden\mondrian\tree\_tree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden\mondrian\tree\_tree.obj -O3" failed with exit status 127

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for scikit-garden
  Running setup.py clean for scikit-garden
Failed to build scikit-garden
Installing collected packages: scikit-garden
  Running setup.py install for scikit-garden ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\KYLEM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-6w93qccz\\scikit-garden\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\KYLEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9f_jrw1m-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Appending skgarden.mondrian.tree configuration to skgarden.mondrian
    Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'skgarden.mondrian' to 'skgarden.mondrian.tree')
    Appending skgarden.mondrian.ensemble configuration to skgarden.mondrian
    Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'skgarden.mondrian' to 'skgarden.mondrian.ensemble')
    Appending skgarden.mondrian configuration to skgarden
    Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'skgarden' to 'skgarden.mondrian')
    Appending skgarden.quantile configuration to skgarden
    Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from 'skgarden' to 'skgarden.quantile')
    Appending skgarden configuration to
    Ignoring attempt to set 'name' (from '' to 'skgarden')
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building extension "skgarden.mondrian.tree._tree" sources
    building extension "skgarden.mondrian.tree._splitter" sources
    building extension "skgarden.mondrian.tree._criterion" sources
    building extension "skgarden.mondrian.tree._utils" sources
    build_src: building npy-pkg config files
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden
    copying skgarden\forest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden
    copying skgarden\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden
    copying skgarden\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian
    copying skgarden\mondrian\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian
    copying skgarden\mondrian\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
    copying skgarden\quantile\ensemble.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
    copying skgarden\quantile\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
    copying skgarden\quantile\tree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
    copying skgarden\quantile\utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
    copying skgarden\quantile\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\quantile
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\ensemble
    copying skgarden\mondrian\ensemble\forest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\ensemble
    copying skgarden\mondrian\ensemble\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\ensemble
    copying skgarden\mondrian\ensemble\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\ensemble
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\tree
    copying skgarden\mondrian\tree\setup.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\tree
    copying skgarden\mondrian\tree\tree.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\tree
    copying skgarden\mondrian\tree\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\skgarden\mondrian\tree
    running build_ext
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
    customize MSVCCompiler using build_ext
    building 'skgarden.mondrian.tree._tree' extension
    compiling C sources
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden\mondrian
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden\mondrian\tree
    cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcskgarden\mondrian\tree\_tree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden\mondrian\tree\_tree.obj -O3

    error: Command "cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include -IC:\Anaconda3\include /Tcskgarden\mondrian\tree\_tree.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\skgarden\mondrian\tree\_tree.obj -O3" failed with exit status 127

    ----------------------------------------
Command "C:\Anaconda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\KYLEM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-6w93qccz\\scikit-garden\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\KYLEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-9f_jrw1m-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\KYLEM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-6w93qccz\scikit-garden\
```

Comment: what happens when you try to install the development version?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that?  I apologize as I am somewhat new to this but running pip install 'git+https://github.com/scikit-garden/scikit-garden' doesn't work.